# How can I pass a component in 2 different stack navigator screens without both of these screens becoming the same thing?

Tags: javascript, react-native

> Let's say in this case:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={BottomTab}
  options = {{title:'Home', headerShown: false}}
  />
  
        
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Create' component={BottomTab}
  options = {{title:'Create'}}
```

> Now the problem is the "Create" screen contains the exact same things as the "Home" screen because they both have the same BottomTab component. So how can I have the same BottomTabNavigator in both screens without both of them becoming the same thing? Note: These Stack.Screen are both in the same Stack Navigator and the same NavigationContainer if it is relevant to know.
>
> My BottomTab component's code:

```
function BottomTab() {
return (
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      labelStyle: {fontSize:18},
      activeTintColor: 'green',
      tabBarVisible:false,
      tabBarShowLabel: false,
    }}
    >

  
    <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <Ionicons
        name={focused ? "home" : "home-outline"}
        size={20}
        color = {focused ? "black" : "#748c94"}
        type={'Ionicons'}
        />
      )
    }}
    />



    <Tab.Screen
      name="Search"
      component={Search} 
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <Ionicons
          name={focused ? "search" : "search-outline"}
          size={20}
          color = {focused ? "black" : "#748c94"}
          type={'Ionicons'}
          />          
        )
      }} 
    />
    

    <Tab.Screen
      name="Topic"
      component={EmptyScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('HHH')} underlayColor="white" activeOpacity={1}>
            <View 
            style={{
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              borderRadius: 50,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <AddButton/>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        )
      }}  
    />
    

    <Tab.Screen
      name="Notification"
      component={Notification}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <Ionicons
          name={focused ? "notifications" : "notifications-outline"}
          size={20}
          color = {focused ? "black" : "#748c94"}
          type={'Ionicons'}
          />          
        )
      }}  
    />

    
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Message"
      component={Message}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <Ionicons
          name={focused ? "mail" : "mail-outline"}
          size={20}
          color = {focused ? "black" : "#748c94"}
          type={'Ionicons'}
          />          
        )
      }}  
    />

  </Tab.Navigator>  
  );
}
```

Comment: what's the end result you're trying to make? If you pass the same component to the Screen obviously it will give you the same BottomTab component. If you can describe more about what you're trying to achieve, we'll probably able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid passing your BottomTabNavigator component to both screens and instead have a 'main' screen where you put your tab navigator like so :

```
import React from 'react';
import TabNavigator from '../navigators/TabNavigator';

const HomeScreen = ({}) => {
  return <TabNavigator />;
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: then you can put this HomeScreen in your StackNavigator and put the StackNavigator in your App.js NavigationContainer